# my CSS background will not show on github pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I created a page on GitHub, however the background I coded through CSS will not appear on my page. The `CSS` code is shown below.

```
header {
  background-image: url("resources/img/antelope.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

My github repo is: https://github.com/person/person.github.io

The CSS file is stored here:

https://github.com/person/person.github.io/blob/master/resources/css/style.css

Any help to why my background will not appear will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your image is not inside the `resources` folder.... it is at the same level as the `index.html` page - your URL should be `url("antelope.JPG");`

Comment: the final URL will depend on how you build your page.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Code or markup in a jsfiddle can change or go dead making your question and the answers useless. See: [mcve]

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is not inside the `resources` folder.... it is at the same level as the `index.html` page - your URL should be `url("antelope.JPG");`

**UPDATE**

Looking at your changes, the URL should be as below now:

If you do not do anything, the URL should be: `resources/img/antelope.jpg`

if you package resources into the root folder then: `./img/antelope.jpg`

but, the final URL will depend on how you build your page and beware that the server might be case-sensitive.

**Make sure you indicate the correct filename (including case-sensitive extension)**

Something along the lines of

```css
header {
  background-image: url(./img/antelope.jpg); /* may need to be adjusted depending on how you build your page */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    Some navigation here
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: That was a mistake. header {
    background-image: url("resources/img/antelope.JPG");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
} should be the actual css code. however it still does not work

Comment: @ant did the change in the URL fix things for you?

Comment: no it didnt not fix the issue. it works locally but not through github.

Comment: @ant inside the `/img/` folder, the image name is not *capital* JPG but *lowercase* jpg... did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

To use one from the root directory (https://github.com/anhthyngo/anhthyngo.github.io) use next CSS:

```
header {
    background-image: url('../../antelope.JPG');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

to use from `img` directory use next CSS:

```
header {
    background-image: url(../img/antelope.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can change CSS directly in the browser. Did you push your changes to GitHub?

Comment: it should be background-image: url('../../antelope.JPG');  instead of background-image: url('../../antelope.jpg');

Comment: thank you that code worked. it was the case sensitivity